# Is it possible to react to click event on SharePoint list element click event?

Tags: sharepoint, events, click

Is it possible to react to click event on SharePoint list element click event?
I have a list at SharePoint site. One of fields is a hyperlink. I would like to react when I click on this hyperlink.

Any ideas?

Comment: React how? On the webpage direclty? or in the background in your code. Are you working on client side with client obj model or creating an app using server obj model or creating a web-part that works on the click event? Your question is too vague.

Comment: I want to react in the background code on server side. To be more concrete I have a web-part with control LinkButton. When I click it list begins to fill. There are 4 columns in this list. 3 of columns are just text type and one is "hyperlink or image". When list is being filled I assign to hyperlink value Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue and property Url = "http://localhost". But I want to assign to hyperlink Url property value "http://stackoverflow.com" (for example) when I click on this link. Hopefully, it's not so vague now...

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible 
You give onclick event like that ..
may it is helpful for you

```
<div onClick={this.handleclick.bind(this)}/>
```